# Undefined "___divmodsi4" linking Monotouch project with static library in release mode

Tags: xamarin.ios, linker-errors

I have a Monotouch project linked to a static library containing C++ modules.
Monotouch version: 3.0.3.5
XCode version:     4.4.1
C/C++ Compiler:    Apple LLVM 4.0

When building the project in debug mode for iOS simulator and iOS device everything is OK -
application is linked and runs.
However when building the release configuration for iOS device the following error appears:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "___divmodsi4"
```

The following line from the static library code somehow causes the trouble:

```
 int number_of_buckets = num_samples / window_samples_step;
```

If this line is modified as follows the problem disappears:

```
 int number_of_buckets = (int)((float)num_samples / (float)window_samples_step);
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix the problem without the above modification?

Thanks,
Ury.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs near the end of the build and generally depends on it's original parameters. Try to compare your options between your **Release** and **Debug** builds and check that:

- you are using the same **Additional mtouch arguments** on both configuration;
- you are using the same compiler, **Mono AOT versus LLVM compilers**, on both configuration;
- you are using the same architecture, **ARMv6 versus ARMv7**, on both configuration.

Otherwise attach (e.g. preferable to a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) or pastebin) the full build log (from the **Build Output** of MonoDevelop's **Error Pad**) for both **Debug** and **Release** builds.

To be more helpful add "-v -v -v" to the **Additional mtouch arguments** before re-building. This will augment the verbosity (details) about each steps.

Comment: **Additional mtouch arguments** are the same, except for necessary changes (Release vs Debug). 
The same compiler **LLVM** is used on both configurations and **ARMv7** is the architecture for both. 
I put the **Build Output** in < https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE22849619D3313B!104&authkey=!AFA8-APDCl86H3E > Thanks, Ury.

Comment: I can't access that URL (ask for credentials). Please fill a bug report with the data.

Comment: I hope it is fixed. Please try again.

Comment: To diagnose such issue both debug (working) and release (not working) logs are needed.

Comment: I put in < https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE22849619D3313B!109&authkey=!AEjoIgs1qolTGDE > all 4 configurations. Release/Debug and Iphone/iPhoneSimulator. Of these only the Release iPhoneSimulator configuration has the link error, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the app's Deployment Target (in the project's options, Build / iPhone Application page) to at least 5.0.